# Stop updatepanel updating when using __doPostBack on another updatepanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel, dopostback

I have an issue with a .NET updatepanel updating when I don't want it to.

I am using a combination of .NET Ajax and Twitter Bootstrap Javascript.  I have two update panels on a page (You will notice both panels have ChildrenAsTriggers set to false and UpdateMode set to conditional, hence the fact that I'm at a loss!!):

PANEL 1:

```
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upAreas" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Literal ID="litEmptyAreas" runat="server" Text="You currently have no goals or actions." Visible="false" />
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptAreas" runat="server" 
                        OnItemDataBound="getAreaGoals" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                                <div class="accordion-group" id="areagroup">
                                <div class="accordion-heading area-heading">
                                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href='#collapse-<%# Eval("area_id") %>' >
                                        <div class="areatitle">
                                        <asp:Literal ID="litAreaTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("area_title") %>' />
                                        <!-- <span class="areacreatedate"><asp:Literal ID="litAreaCreateDate" runat="server" Text='<%# "created " + String.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy}", Eval("area_createdate")) %>' /></span>-->
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="areaicons">
                                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target= "#myModal"><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white areaiconplus"></i></a>
                                        <!--<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target= "#myModal"><i class="icon-file icon-white areaiconlist"></i></a>-->
                                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target= "#myModal"><i class="icon-eye-open icon-white areaiconeye"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id='collapse-<%# Eval("area_id") %>' class="accordion-body collapse">
                                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                                    <asp:Literal ID="litEmptyGoals" runat="server" Text="You currently have no goals or actions for this life area." Visible="true" />
                                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptGoals" runat="server"
                                        OnItemDataBound="setUpGoals" >
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <div class="theGoals clearfix">      
                                                <span class="goalid"><%# Eval("goal_id") %></span>          
                                                <span class="goaltitle"><asp:Literal ID="theGoal" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("goal_title") %>' /></span>
                                                <div class="goalicons">
                                                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target= "#myModal"><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white goal_iconplus"></i></a>
                                                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target= "#myModal"><i class="icon-eye-open icon-white goal_iconeye"></i></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <span class="goalduedate"><asp:Literal ID="theDuedate" runat="server" Text='<%# "<span>Due:</span> " + String.Format("{0:dd MMM yy}", Eval("goal_duedate")) %>' Visible="true" /></span>
                                            </div>                                        
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>                    
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is populated at Page_Load, but may need to be updated later in the event of a user adding a new item.

When the user clicks on a div in this update panel, it should up date the second update panel on the page.  (FYI The panels are not nested)

PANEL 2:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upActionlist" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" OnLoad="getActions" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="listheading">
                        <div class="goaltitle">
                            <asp:Literal ID="litGoalTitle" runat="server" Text="Nationally Recognised Consultancy" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="goalicons">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target= "#myModal"><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white goaliconplus"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target= "#myModal"><i class="icon-eye-open icon-white goaliconeye"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="listinner">
                        <asp:Literal ID="litEmptyActions" runat="server" Text="You currently have no actions to view." Visible="true" />
                        <asp:Repeater ID="rptActions" runat="server" 
                            OnItemDataBound="setUpActions">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <div class="theActions clearfix">
                                    <div class="actiontitle">      
                                        <span class="actionid"><%# Eval("item_id") %></span>          
                                        <asp:Literal ID="theAction" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("item_title") %>' />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="actionicons">
                                        <!--<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target= "#myModal"><i class="icon-th-list icon-white actioniconlist"></i></a>
                                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target= "#myModal"><i class="icon-file icon-white actioniconnote"></i></a>-->
                                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target= "#myModal"><i class="icon-eye-open icon-white actioniconeye"></i></a>
                                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target= "#myModal"><i class="icon-check icon-white actioniconcomplete"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="actiondate">
                                        <span class="actionduedate"><asp:Literal ID="theActionduedate" runat="server" Text='<%# "<span>Due:</span> " + String.Format("{0:dd MMM yy}", Eval("item_duedate")) %>' Visible="true" /></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The update is called using the following javascipt click event added to the DIV in the first update panel in document.ready:

```
        $('.theGoals').click(function () {
            //remove from all goal other classes
            $('.theGoals').removeClass('active'); // "this" is the current element in the loop

            $(this).addClass('active');

            // Load content
            __doPostBack('<%=upActionlist.ClientID %>', $(this).children('.goaltitle').text() + "|" + $(this).children('.goalid').text());

        });
```

When this javascript it run, it updates both panels, not just the second panel.  Any help gratefully received, as this is driving me mad.

Answer (score 0):

I get around this problem by putting a hidden `asp:button` on the page and calling it's click method from the client-side for force a proper postback:

**JS:**

```
$('#<%=bla.ClientID %>').click();
```